# puppet / facter: "created(corrective)"

Tags: puppet

I use puppet to update / maintain itself (among other things). For some reason every time the client runs I get these two actions:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Servers::Packages::Puppet/Package[facter]/ensure: created (corrective)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Servers::Packages::Puppet/Package[puppet]/ensure: created (corrective)
```

The definitions in question look like this:

```
    package { 'puppet' :
            ensure => 'latest',
            require => Package['facter'];
    }

    package { 'facter' :
            ensure => 'latest',
    }

    file { '/etc/default/puppet' :
            ensure => 'file',
            mode => '644',
            source => 'puppet:///modules/servers/packages/puppet/default';
    }

    file{ '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf' :
            mode => '644',
            content => template("servers/packages/puppet/puppet_conf.erb"),
            require => Package[ 'puppet' ];
    }

    service{ 'puppet' :
            ensure => 'running',
            enable => true,
            require => Package[ 'puppet' ],
            subscribe => [
                    File[ '/etc/default/puppet'],
                    File[ '/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf'],
            ];
    }
```

What's wrong with my definition(s)? Why do puppet / facter appear to be reinstalled with every run?

Comment: Is this Puppet Enterprise or free version? This also looks like a rather old version of Puppet. Could you specify that too?

Comment: Puppet seems able to identify the packages by the names 'puppet' and 'facter', but perhaps those are not the packages' actual names.  For example, as Puppet is currently packaged for RHEL by Puppet, Inc., both `puppet` and `facter` are provided by the `puppet-agent` package.  Its metadata specify that it provides features "puppet" and "facter", allowing the package manager to map those names to that package.

Comment: This installation uses puppet 6.x - though it is the free-ware version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Puppet 4, Puppet, Inc. has provided only all-in-one packages of client-side components, not named either 'puppet' or 'facter'.  The package for Puppet 6 is named `puppet-agent` -- this is what you should be managing, not packages named 'puppet' or 'facter'.

The messages you report indicate that Puppet does not see up-to-date 'puppet' or 'facter' packages, which is natural because these do not exist.  They also indicate that puppet thinks it has corrected the problem -- which it will have attempted to do by installing / updating packages with those names, and which apparently succeeded.  This seeming incongruity will have arisen because the puppet-agent packages declare that they provide features named "puppet" and "facter", which your package manager is using to associate those package names with the puppet-agent package. As a result, the installation / update succeeds without actually installing anything new, leaving the system primed to do the same thing over again on the next run.

I suspect that the "(corrective)" marks on the log output reflect package-manager exit statuses indicating success without doing anything.